# Apply SSL and www in main domain and not in subdomain in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am working on to apply SSL (https) and www to domain ("https:// www.xyz.com") in the browser whenever I type anything for the domain ("xyz.com").

I have subdomains as well and I don't want to apply "www" in subdomains (this is working fine).

Everything is working great except if I type "https:// xyz.com" in the browser, ngingx doesn't apply www (it should be "https:// www.xyz.com") but it gives "https:// xyz.com" only.

Following is the config file of sites-available:

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name xyz.com *.xyz.com;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xyz.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.xyz.com.key;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
       proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
       proxy_buffer_size 128k;
       proxy_buffers 16 64k;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       location ~* /web/static/ {
           proxy_buffering off;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
       }
   }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://www.$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.xyz.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

move `add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;` option to ssl server block with 443 port.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
  # rest configs
}
```

Change http 80 block to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;  # permenent redirect
}
```

NOTE: any changes made to nginx config needs a `reload` signal to nginx process to apply the changes in ubuntu it requires `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but it's not working.
When I type "https:// xyz.com" in browser, it doesn't apply www with it.

Comment: you still have that rewrite block ? or replaced with `return 301` & also check in private browser window

Comment: I commented/removed the rewrite block and added return 301.
Yes, I checked in private window as well.

Comment: after applying changes to the conf you tested & reloaded nginx process ri8 ?

Comment: Yes, I did restart/reload the nginx after changing the cofig file.

Comment: You have to remove both rewrite blocks, also in the non-ssl server you should use the same server_name variable that you use in the ssl server. Only two server blocks